# Variable is local & global scope in a Python function

Tags: python, mongodb

I am learning Python and have come across a strange problem which I think is down to local / global varable scope. The problem is in this function...

```
def mongo_execute_command(db, database, command, inc_mongo_name):
    doc = db[database].command(command)
    if inc_mongo_name:
        doc['mongo_server'] = db.HOST + ":" + str(db.PORT)
    return doc
```

The **db** variable is a connection to a MongoDB server and I have other code that iterates across clusters / shards. It does this correctly, the issue lies with add the value for **mongo_server**. It always adds localhost:27017 regardless of the actual connection passed in. I know this because when I change the code to..

```
def mongo_execute_command(db, database, command, inc_mongo_name):
    doc = db[database].command(command)
    print db
    if inc_mongo_name:
        print db.HOST + ":" + str(db.PORT)
        doc['mongo_server'] = db.HOST + ":" + str(db.PORT)
    return doc
```

This is the output (annotated) when executed against a cluster..

```
MongoClient(u'localhost.localdomain', 30001) <-- Correct, expected
localhost:27017 <- Why is this here?
MongoClient(u'localhost.localdomain', 30002)
localhost:27017
MongoClient(u'localhost.localdomain', 30003)
localhost:27017
MongoClient(u'localhost.localdomain', 30004)
localhost:27017
MongoClient(u'localhost.localdomain', 30005)
localhost:27017
MongoClient(u'localhost.localdomain', 30006)
localhost:27017
```

Why does 'db' contain the correct details, but when I reference db.PROPERTY, does it refer to (I assume) a global instance of that variable?

I am using Python 2.6.6.

Many thanks.

**UPDATE**

As Bruno correctly pointed out this is nothing to do with scope. For some reason the properties in PyMongo (3.0.3) are ignoring the provided value and setting them to defaults...

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

c = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
print c
print c.HOST
print str(c.PORT)
c.close()

c = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:30001/test")
print c
print c.HOST
print str(c.PORT)

c = MongoClient("localhost", 30001)
print c
print c.HOST
print str(c.PORT)

c = MongoClient(host="localhost", port=30001)
print c
print c.HOST
print str(c.PORT)
```

Console output is as follows...

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> 
>>> c = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
>>> print c
MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
>>> print c.HOST
localhost
>>> print str(c.PORT)
27017
>>> c.close()
>>> 
>>> c = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:30001/test")
>>> print c
MongoClient('localhost', 30001)
>>> print c.HOST
localhost
>>> print str(c.PORT)
27017
>>> 
>>> c = MongoClient("localhost", 30001)
>>> print c
MongoClient('localhost', 30001)
>>> print c.HOST
localhost
>>> print str(c.PORT)
27017
>>> 
>>> c = MongoClient(host="localhost", port=30001)
>>> print c
MongoClient('localhost', 30001)
>>> print c.HOST
localhost
>>> print str(c.PORT)
27017
```

Comment: It's definitly not a "local/global scope" issue - without a `global db` statement in your function Python will NOT try to lookup `db` in the global scope, and if you try to add a `global db` statement Python will raise a `SyntaxError` since `db` is known as a function param, hence by definition local. IOW: the problem is very probably somewhere in whatever `db` is.

Comment: OK. Thanks. A global / local issue was the only thing that made sense to me. type(db) returns <class 'pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient'>

Comment: Then read the source and find out what happens...